# Linq date format

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to populate a gridview with, among other things, a date field using a LINQ query that pulls data from an Oracle database. My problem is the date format that winds up displaying in the gridview is: `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS`. I only want to show `MM/DD/YYYY`. What change do I need to make to my query to achieve this?

```
 Dim InfoDetails = 
    From Lines In dtMain _
    Where Lines.Field(Of String)("ULTIMATE_PARENT_NAME") = lstUPs.SelectedItem.ToString _
        And Lines.Field(Of String)("CHANGE_TYPE") = Chng_Type.ToString _     
        And Not Lines.Field(Of String)("WARNING_TYPE").StartsWith("WARNING: DATA L") _
    Group By Change_Title = Lines.Field(Of String)("TITLE"), _
             Change_Details = Lines.Field(Of String)("DESCRIPTION"), _
             Effective_Date = Lines.Field(Of Date)("EFFECTIVE_DATE"), _
             Change_Type = Lines.Field(Of String)("CHANGE_TYPE") _
    Into Fieldname = Group, Count()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either specify the format in the grid (recommended) or change the output type to a string:

```
Effective_Date = Lines.Field(Of Date)("EFFECTIVE_DATE").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), _
```

I would *strongly* recommend setting the format in the grid, but since you didn't specify anything about the UI I can't give any specific advice.

Some drawbacks of converting to string are:

1. Sorting would be inaccurate with the format you've chosen
2. You can't re-use this for other UIs that would want a different format.

Comment: +1 Always store the data in the correct way and do formatting on the way out for display - anything else will come back and bite you on the ass at some time in the future

Comment: +1 for `You can either specify the format in the grid (recommended)`.

Comment: Got it...as you recommended I set the format in the gridview. Thanks for the replies!